# Stored procedure to validate xml content against dtd

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, xml

I have a stored procedure which creates xml content and then is stored to a xml file. Is it possible to validate the generated xml content against a dtd file?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to validate XML against a DTD file using SQL Server.

You can validate the XML with a XSD stored in a [XML Schema Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187856.aspx) using a [strong typed XML variable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184277.aspx)

```
DECLARE @x xml(YourXMLSchemaCollectionName);
SET @X = 'YourXML';
```